# Not able to avoid ElementNotVisibleException even though I'm using a try and except method

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to download millions of excel files from a website using selenium. My current code tries to handle issues with ElementNotVisibleException, but my "try and except" methods seems to fall short.

I have tried to implement a try and except solution, where if the error message appears I have instructed Selenium to wait untill the "button" appears.

```
import os
import time
import csv
from tqdm import tqdm
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException

working_directory = r"xx"
os.chdir(working_directory)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 

prefs = {
        "download.default_directory": r"xx",
       "download.prompt_for_download": False,
       "download.directory_upgrade": True}

options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:xxx\chromedriver.exe", options = options) 

driver.get("website")

# Login
driver.find_element_by_class_name("smallLoginBox").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(1)
time.sleep(2) 
driver.find_element_by_id('loginFormUC_loginEmailTextBox').send_keys('EMAIL')
driver.find_element_by_id('loginFormUC_loginPasswordTextBox').send_keys('PASWORD')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Logg inn']").click()

# Get a custom list of firms
bedrifter  = []

with open("./listwithIDs.csv") as csvDataFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
    for row in csvReader:
        bedrifter.append(row[0])

# THE LOOP

for ID in tqdm(bedrifter_gjenstår):
    driver.get("website" + ID)
    source = driver.page_source

    if not "Ingen data" in source: # make sure there is an excel file. If not, loop continues to next ID.
        # first click on button "download excel"
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_id("exportExcel").click()
        except ElementNotVisibleException:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "exportExcel")))
            driver.find_element_by_id("exportExcel").click()
        except ElementClickInterceptedException:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "exportExcel")))
            driver.find_element_by_id("exportExcel").click()

        # second click, choosing what format the excel file should be in
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_id("mainContentPlaceHolder_mainContentPlaceHolder_mainContentPlaceHolder_AccountingNumberTableUc_excelLinkButton").click()
        except ElementNotVisibleException:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "mainContentPlaceHolder_mainContentPlaceHolder_mainContentPlaceHolder_AccountingNumberTableUc_excelLinkButton")))
            driver.find_element_by_id("mainContentPlaceHolder_mainContentPlaceHolder_mainContentPlaceHolder_AccountingNumberTableUc_excelLinkButton").click()

# code to switch between windows to remove download window and continue the code
        try: 
            window_export = driver.window_handles[1]
        except IndexError:
            time.sleep(3)
            print("sleep")
            window_export = driver.window_handles[1]

        try:
            window_main = driver.window_handles[0]
        except IndexError:
            time.sleep(3)
            print("sleep")
            window_main = driver.window_handles[0]

        driver.switch_to.window(window_export)
        driver.close()
        driver.switch_to.window(window_main)
```

I expect the code to download all files if there are any, but either ElementNotVisibleException or ElementClickInterceptedException appears.

Comment: one thing to keep in mind is that driver.find_element_by() expects your element to be ready to go when hitting this line of code. It uses the word 'find' but it's more like 'hey, driver, I promise it's there, take a look."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure the element is not only *present* and *visible* but also **clickable** check for clicability as a wait condition:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "exportExcel"))).click()
```

More on Python waits can be found [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits).

Comment: That seems to work. The other problem which seems to occur when I try to switch between the two chrome windows, is an error "Index out of range". This happends specifically on ```try: 
            window_export = driver.window_handles[1]
        except IndexError:
            time.sleep(3)
            print("sleep")
            window_export = driver.window_handles[1]```


Can I use a similar waiting function to let selenium know "wait until both windows have loaded, then perform the operations of switching between the two windows"?

Comment: There is `expected_conditions.number_of_windows_to_be`, `expected_conditions.new_window_is_opened` or others [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Before perform any operation on the element first check it is visible or not 
Here is the example code:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 15)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(("element_path")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("element_path").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably get these exceptions because they occur inside an `except` clause and not inside a `try`. Please look at the traceback to determine which line threw the exception. This should tell you where the problem lies.
Also, if you want to wait for the element to be visible you should use `visibility_of_element_located` instead of `presence_of_element_located`